# KEY_ENTER doesnt work on Sensehat joystick input for a case statement

Tags: c, event-handling, raspberry-pi3

im trying to check for the event input on a sensehat for raspberry
I already checked the eventtype with evtest und it says KEY_ENTER when I press the Joystick

```
void MovePlayer(unsigned int code)
{
    int i;
    switch (code) {
        case '\r': case '\n': case KEY_ENTER:
            printf("works");
            i = CheckPoint();
            printf("works");
            if (i=0){
                zaehler++;
                printf("success");
                }
            else 
                //looselife or game
                printf("error");

            break;
        case KEY_UP:
            player.x--;
            if (player.x<0)
                player.x=7;
            break;
        case KEY_RIGHT:
            player.y++;
            if (player.y>7)
                player.y=0;
            break;
        case KEY_DOWN:
            player.x ++;
            if (player.x>7)
                player.x=0;
            break;
        case KEY_LEFT:
            player.y--;
            if (player.y<0)
                player.y=7;
            break;
    }
}
```

This is what the code looks like all the other keys work just fine 
i already tried out something i found in here but this was mainly for enterkey on keyboard

Comment: `if (i=0){` → `if (i == 0) {`

Comment: oh yeah thx :p doesnt solve the problem but yeah i overlooked this one :p